# How to write specific application for facebook?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, documentation

Please help me with documentation to write specific application for Facebook.
Need to know, what language to choose? is specific facebook API? is documentation for API? is site with samples catalogue? need to know all related info. Some words about app, it would be app, which compare users interests.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pretty much any language, with PHP being one of the most popular ones (after all, Facebook was written in PHP). In order to get started, check out one of the following introductory articles on Facebook app development.

**Intros**

[HOWTO: Create a Facebook App with Google App Engine and Best Buy Remix](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/shelftalkers.html)

[How to Write Your Own Facebook App in 5 Minutes](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tutorial-write-a-facebook-application/10116/)

[How To Build A Facebook Application](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/building_facebook_applications/)

**Facebook docs**

[Facebook Dev Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)

[Facebook Developer Group](http://www.facebook.com/developers/)

[Build the social and personalized web.](http://developers.facebook.com/)

**Other useful stuff**

[Monetizing Facebook applications](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/social/monetizing-facebook-applications/215)

Comment: It is possible to add own app to comon apps on facebook?

Comment: do you have own app? in other way thanks for topics

Comment: I've been involved in app development. Yes, you can add your app to the application directory on Facebook.

Comment: is there some statistics about facebook apps?

Answer (score 1):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

(first result when googling "facebook development api")

Comment: @alex: yes, but how is that related to your question?

Comment: need advice of expirienced developers...

Comment: Then you're at the right place here on SO :)

Comment: @Alex you may be better off trying to hire someone than doing it yourself, depending on the complexity of the project, your motivations, background, etc.

Comment: is a better resource where i can ask question? or stackoverflow better?!

Comment: @Alex I suggest you read some of the articles I posted and look at Piskvor's link. I'd try to understand as much as possible, dabble around for a while, and then give us more specific questions. Otherwise, you can always try the Facebook developer forums; but there, make sure you've read anything you can find on the subject because they're not very friendly there if you're not putting forth effort.

Comment: SO is good, but you need to ask *specific* questions. Asking "I need to build an application, how?" will get you a "go read the documentation, try to *actually* build an app, come back when you have specific problems". Show us that you actually put some effort into it, and you may get a useful answer.